# I edited a new person's question and a user called Community accepted my edit?

Tags: discussion, support

This user https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community. Is a moderator with this description:

Hi, I'm not really a person.

I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!

I do things like

- Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
- Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
- Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
- Own suggested edits from anonymous users
- Remove abandoned questions

It accepted my edit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13199333). But why?

Comment: See the "Sometimes the Community user approves or rejects my edit. What does that mean?" section of this post: [How do suggested edits work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/300411)

Comment: While we're at it, please note that things like "Thanks in advance" should be removed from posts, not added. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) for the relevant discussion. This was one of the improvements that the reviewer made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user [heinzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87698/heinzi) reviewed your suggested edit, chose <kbd>Improve edit</kbd> and edited the post even further. Whenever somebody chooses <kbd>Improve edit</kbd> or <kbd>Reject and edit</kbd>, this is shown as a 'binding' vote by the Community user. It wouldn't make sense for a normal user to have a 'binding' accept/reject vote.